# Simple algebra over algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory, lie-algebras

In Jacobson's *Lie Algebras*, page 303, it seems he uses the following result:

> If $\mathfrak L$ is a simple finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field $\Omega$ which is the algebraic closure of a field $\Phi$, then there exists a basis for $\mathfrak L$ whose multiplication coefficients are in $\Phi$.

Is this theorem true as stated, and can someone give me a reference to a proof in some textbook? Preferably in Jacobson's books or in Lang's *Algebra*, if possible.

Comment: This is explained on page $303$ in Jacobson's book, see section $4$, conditions for isomorphism. See also the section "Chevalley basis" in Humphrey's book on Lie algebras.

Comment: It was page 303 I was referring to...

Comment: In my version, he deos little more than stating it. My version is from 1962.

Comment: In characteristic zero this follows from the classification of simple Lie algebras, which shows moreover that you can find a basis for which the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. I have no idea what happens in positive characteristic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Jacobson assumes in this chapter that the field is arbitrary, but of characteristic zero. In prime characteristic a Chevalley basis need not exist, in fact, it exists exactly for the simple Lie algebras of classical type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page $313$ Jacobson gives the following reasoning ($4$ lines before lemma $3$):

"$L$ is simple over the algebraically closed field $\Omega$. Hence it has a basis over $\Omega$ whose multiplication coefficients are in the prime field and so are in $\Phi$."

That the coefficients are in the prime field follows from the classification. There is even a basis (a so-called *Chevalley basis*) such that the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. Tensoring this $\mathbb{Z}$-Lie algebra with any field $F$ gives a Lie algebra over $F$.

For more details on a Chevalley basis and the reduction modulo a prime $p$ see Chapter VII, section $25$ in the book [Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387900537) by James E. Humphreys.